# How can I set Unknown as column's value when there isn't any user's name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) full_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u 
ON p.author_id = u.id AND p.visibility = 1
```

My query returns an user's full name *(both his first and last name as a single string)* where the value of `visibility` column equals `1`. But sometimes the value of `visibility` column isn't `1`, it is `0`. In that case, my query returns nothing. Well that's not what I want. I want either: `{user's full name}` or the string of `Unknown`.

So I need to check if `full_name` is empty, then set it the word of `Unknown`. I can do that by PHP after fetching. But I want to know how can I do that by pure MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `CASE`, and you probably will also need `COALESCE` for the nulls values.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN p.visibility = 1 
            THEN COALESCE(CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname), 'Unknown')
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END as full_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u 
ON p.author_id = u.id
```

Comment: What about just `SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname), 'Unknown') as full_nam . . . ` ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh You still need the `CASE` for `p.visibility = 1 `

Comment: I guess you can leave that condition on the `ON` clause, like exactly how OP does. Am I right?

Comment: @Shafizadeh well that may work, but not sure how is related the p.visibility with the fname and lname. So without data I will be guessing.